# Solidifying a melted data frame?

Tags: r, reshape2

Assuming I have a melted `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
  variable       value
1         A -0.19933093
2         A -1.19043346
3         A -1.32248172
4         A -1.98644507
5         A -0.07930953
6         B -0.10074686
7         B  0.72451483
8         B -0.40914044
9         B  0.02913376
10        B  0.16062491
```

How do I get it to:

```
  A       B
-0.19933093 -0.10074686
-1.19043346  0.72451483
-1.32248172 -0.40914044
-1.98644507  0.02913376
-0.07930953  0.16062491
```

Seems trivial but I am blanking on an answer. `dcast` and `acast` do not seem to do it. My goal is to do this on larger datasets and turn the end product into a `matrix` with the column names to be the variable names. I tried playing with `daply` and `laply` (before melting) without much luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `unstack`:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "variable       value
1         A -0.19933093
2         A -1.19043346
3         A -1.32248172
4         A -1.98644507
5         A -0.07930953
6         B -0.10074686
7         B  0.72451483
8         B -0.40914044
9         B  0.02913376
10        B  0.16062491",sep = "",header = TRUE)

> unstack(dat,value~variable)

            A           B
1 -0.19933093 -0.10074686
2 -1.19043346  0.72451483
3 -1.32248172 -0.40914044
4 -1.98644507  0.02913376
5 -0.07930953  0.16062491
```

But I should add that I would love to know how to do this using `dcast`, as I've also tried repeatedly and haven't been able to.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `dcast` without adding another column as the `variable` column alone doesn't uniquely identify each data point. Put more loosely, it doesn't know which row to put the values into.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, begin with a data frame in wide form, containing an id. `melt()` it to give the long form, then `dcast()` it to get back to the original data frame.

```
library(reshape2)
df = read.table(text = "id   A   B
1  1 -0.19933093 -0.10074686
2  2 -1.19043346  0.72451483
3  3 -1.32248172 -0.40914044
4  4 -1.98644507  0.02913376
5  5 -0.07930953  0.16062491", sep = "", header = TRUE)

df

df.melt = melt(df, "id")
df.melt

df.original = dcast(df.melt, id~variable)

df.original
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `acast()` to return a matrix. It needs an id variable.

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- read.table(text = "variable       value
1         A -0.19933093
2         A -1.19043346
3         A -1.32248172
4         A -1.98644507
5         A -0.07930953
6         B -0.10074686
7         B  0.72451483
8         B -0.40914044
9         B  0.02913376
10        B  0.16062491",sep = "",header = TRUE)

dat$id = rep(1:5, 2)
dat

acast(dat, id~variable)
```

Comment: The id is even easier to add before melting, if that's possible.  (It seems to be in the OPs situation, as it's mentioned above.)